# How to modify a global variable

Tags: javascript

```
const searchbtn = document.getElementById('Search-btn');
const cityinput = document.getElementById('city-input');
const apiKey = 'key';
let lon;
let lat;

function GeoGet() {
    let GeoApiUrl = `http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=${cityinput.value}&limit=1&appid=${apiKey}`
    fetch(GeoApiUrl)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
           lon = data[0].lon;
            lat = data[0].lat;
            console.log(lon)
            console.log(lat)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error();
        });
}
searchbtn.onclick = () => {
    GeoGet();
    console.log(lon);
    console.log(lon);
}
```

I want to change the lon and lat in the function, but it does not work.
I can't understand why

[Console](https://ibb.co/z53gR6W)

Comment: The issue is that fetching from the GeoApi takes time, so the `console.log(lon)` gets run before the geoApi responds to the request and updates the value of `lon`

Comment: Also note that your `searchbtn.onclick` callback is executing `console.log(lon)` twice – I think the intention was to have one for `lon` and one for `lat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in comment and some guys explained in other posts about
[***`fetch`***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API),
So here's solution using `async`&`await`:

```js
let lon;
let lat;
async function GeoGet() {
  let GeoApiUrl = `http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=${cityinput.value}&limit=1&appid=${apiKey}`;
  let response = await fetch(GeoApiUrl);
  let data = await response.json();
  lat = data[0].lat;
  lon = data[0].lon;
}
searchbtn.onclick = async () => {
  await GeoGet();
  console.log(lon);
  console.log(lon);
};
```

Comment: I don't know why, but the site began to identify cities poorly

Comment: is it for time, it takes more than usual ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a `fetch` call, which is a `Promise`, but are not waiting for the `then` callback to be finished before executing the `console.log` in your `onclick`. You'll either need to make `GetGet` an `async` function and call it via `await` in `onclick` (making that `async` too), or place the `console.log`s inside the `then` callback. The latter is preferable, as `await` calls are blocking.

#### Blocking With `async`/`await`

```js
const searchbtn = document.getElementById('Search-btn');
const cityinput = document.getElementById('city-input');
const apiKey = 'key';
let lon;
let lat;

const GeoGet = async () => {
    let GeoApiUrl = `http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=${cityinput.value}&limit=1&appid=${apiKey}`
    try {
        const response = await fetch(GeoApiUrl);
        const json = await response.json(); // await may not be necessary here
        lon = json[0].lon;
        lat = json[0].lat;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }
    return { lon, lat };
};
searchbtn.onclick = async () => {
    await GeoGet();
    console.log(lon);
    console.log(lat);
}
```

#### Non-Blocking With Moving `console.log`s

```js
const searchbtn = document.getElementById('Search-btn');
const cityinput = document.getElementById('city-input');
const apiKey = 'key';
let lon;
let lat;

function GeoGet() {
    let GeoApiUrl = `http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=${cityinput.value}&limit=1&appid=${apiKey}`
    fetch(GeoApiUrl)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            lon = data[0].lon;
            lat = data[0].lat;
            console.log(lon)
            console.log(lat)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error();
        });
}
searchbtn.onclick = () => {
    GeoGet();
}
```

Comment: when I used the async/avyit option, lon and lat were undefined in the console

Comment: Correct you are, there was a bug in my code. I was overriding the global variables using same-named variables in the function. I have since fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you console log the variables before they were changed. This is because the code runs in sync and it does not wait for the response.

Try this:

```
searchbtn.onclick = async () => {
    await GeoGet();
    console.log(lon);
    console.log(lon);
}
```